# If and how are the Coriolis force and gravitation related?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coriolis-effect

I recently got into a discussion whether and how the [Coriolis force/effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_effect) is related to gravitation.

Is gravitation involved in the Coriolis force? If so, how could that be explained?

Comment: it is indeed true that general relativity doesn't really differentiate between inertia and gravity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They really aren't related.  The Coriolis force is essentially conservation of momentum.  Remember that the Earth is (roughly) 24,000 miles in circumference at the equator, and so everything "at rest" on the equator is moving eastward at 1,000 mph.  Away from the equator the ground's eastward speed is slower, roughly 
$$
v_\text{east} = v_\text{equator} \cos \theta
$$
where $\theta$ is the latitude.

So if you have an air mass that moves from the equator to 45º north latitude, it has an "extra" 300 mph eastward speed compared to the ground; if you have air move from 45º north to the equator, the ground at the equator is outpacing it by 300 mph; the net effect is that any amount of north-south motion gets mixed up with east-west motion and gives you swirly storms.

The only role played by gravity is that gravity keeps us all stapled to the earth's surface.

Comment: Hm, since the formula $\vec F_C=2m(\vec v\times\vec\omega_S)$ includes the matter, and due to the principle of equivalence (hope that translation is precise), the gravitation and coriolis force seem related to each other - does this line of thought make any sense?

Comment: @Bachi I'd observe instead that the centripetal acceleration $\vec a = \vec v \times \vec \omega_s$ is independent of the gravitational constant $G$, unlike the gravitational acceleration $g = G M_\text{earth}/R_\text{earth}^2$.

Comment: If gravitational force were virtual like the Coriolis, where would the stapeling derive from? - The Coriolis concept pretends not to know that earth moves, what, then,  might be pretentious about, for instance, gravitational force?

Comment: @PeterBernhard If an object “at rest” on my desk were unaffected by gravity, it would move in a straight line while I follow a circular path around Earth’s axis at my latitude. In my rotating reference frame, the object would rise up off my desk, then fall away to the west, eventually setting in the western sky and rising again as Earth’s spin carried me back around towards my starting point.

Comment: I recommend this comment of yours, of rob. It is worth while imagining. However, what you describe ("would") is real. really is, no dreaming in frames. Anything falling off your desk really moves away from you. In terms of the question: gravity is different from Coriolis, as you do not realize what's not straight about the line.

Answer (score 1):

Corirolis force is simply due to a moving frame of reference.  If you were on a merry-go-round, and threw a ball, it would go straight in the fair-ground frame of reference, but because you see it go away from the direction you threw it, you might suppose it experienced a force.

The earth spins, and because we don't suspect this, we attrit normal inertial motion to a force.

Gravity just keeps us on the ground, and has nothing to do with bending balls in fairgrounds.

Comment: "and threw a ball, ... " - "just" role it (what force makes the ball from the first frame take on the rules of the next frame; gravity it's not. If it's not an earthly play it sure is an inertial one).

Comment: It really doesn't matter if a force is given or not,  What you have to watch out for is that the ball itself does not process in clever ways that bowlers know.  In any case, the same as the fielders running in a curve in the outfield to catch a ball, because in their frame of reference, the ball is travelling straight.

Comment: "It really doesn't matter" (if a force is given or not) is of high general interest. Any regularity held into a formula demands a higher insight: a different frame. To frame someone: to make him believe it's a "travelling straight". Second thought: for any rule thus established your very first words hold true. Empircal regularity need not know about the reasons and causes. Coriolis is the only example I can think of where we know that we know it all. "you're right", so to say.